# T-SQL Query not returning proper results

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012-express

I have a query that I want to capture Sales for Parts.  I am expecting to get the full results from the Parts table and if there are no Sales for that Part in the timeframe, I want to see a 0 in the Sales column.  I am not seeing that.  I am just getting the Parts that had Sales.

```
SELECT
    Part,
    Sum(Sales)
FROM
    dbo.Parts
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.SalesData ON Part = Part
WHERE
    SalesDate > '2011-12-31'
GROUP BY
    Part
ORDER BY
    Part
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Unless Part is in only one table then it is ambiguous.  If part is only in one table then that join is a cross join.

Comment: I understand that.  I was just simplifying the code to get at the hear of the problem.

Comment: Invalid syntax does not get to the "hear" of the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is because your `WHERE` clause is removing all the parts that don't have sales because they won't have a SalesDate.

Try:-

```
SELECT
    Part,
    Sum(Sales)
FROM
    dbo.Parts
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.SalesData ON Part = Part
    AND SalesDate > '2011-12-31'
GROUP BY
    Part
ORDER BY
    Part
```

Comment: He's right:   

You could use `AND COALESCE(salesdate, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) > '2011-12-31'`, which would make the output display sales for every part in the catalog, whether there were actual sales or not.

Comment: Yes.  The main issue was the WHERE condition.  I did not provide the exacting table field names as I don't want to give anything away in case my company gets pissed at me.